# Add two columns and display result in third column in HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
 function = () => {
    var info1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("info1").value);
    var info2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("info2").value);
    var res = Number(info1.value + info2.value);
    var info3 = document.getElementById("info3");
    info3 = Number(res);
 }
```

Now I am getting the answer in alert but not in the `info3`. I am getting `NaN` as output in the third. I know its Not a Number thing but how to convert in so that I get output in my column.

Comment: `function = () = {}` is not a valid definition, btw. You need to either declare it as `const a = () => {}` or `function a(){ }` or `const a = function(){}`

Answer (score 2):

`info1` and `info2` already has the value of the element. You are wrongly trying to access the value again which really does not exists and provides `undefined`. Thus `undefined + undefined` results [**`NaN`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) (Not-A-Number).

Also, `info3` refers to the element, you have to use the `value` property to assign the new value to the element.

**Please Note:** `function = () => {...` is not the valid syntax. Also, as the input value is of type **string**, converting the value to number before setting the value is meaningless.

Try the following way:

```
var myFunction = () => {
  var info1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("info1").value);
  var info2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("info2").value);
  var res = info1 + info2;
  var info3 = document.getElementById("info3");
  info3.value = res; // Number(res) is meaningless here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's return `NaN` make it 0

example `var info1= NaN|0`

```
function = () => {
    var info1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("info1").value) | 0;
    var info2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("info2").value) | 0;
    var res = Number(info1.value + info2.value) | 0;
    var info3 = document.getElementById("info3");
    info3 = Number(res) | 0;
}
```